# Get List of files from solidity to reactjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, ethereum, solidity

I'm new in reactjs & solidity programming.
I wrote simple solidity code that adds files (every file is known by its description and hash) to list of files.
The reactjs part of adding files works fine i can add files via their description and hash.
The problem that i'am facing is that i want each time i add new file, i get its description and hash displayed.

This is the reactjs part of adding  file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Layout from '../../components/Layout';
import { Form, Button, Input, Message } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import auction from '../../src/auction';
import web3 from '../../src/web3';
import { Router} from '../../routes';

class FileNew extends Component {
  state = {
    description: '',
    hash:'',
    fileCounts:'',
    value: ''
  };


  async componentDidMount() {
    const manager = await auction.methods.manager().call();
    const fileCounts = await auction.methods.FileCounts().call();
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log);

    this.setState({ manager, fileCounts, accounts });
  }

  onSubmit = async (event) => {

    this.setState ({ loading: true});

    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts().catch((e) => { console.log(e); });

    await auction.methods.addFile(this.state.description,this.state.hash).send({from : accounts[0]});

    Router.pushRoute('/files/list');

    this.setState ({ loading: false});
  };



  render() {
    return (
  <Layout>
     <h1> Create new file </h1>

      <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

          <Form.Field>
            <label>description</label>
              <Input label="First Name" labelPosition="right"  value={this.state.description}
                onChange={event =>
                  this.setState ({description: event.target.value})} />
          </Form.Field>


          <Form.Field>
            <label>hash</label>
              <Input label="Last Name" labelPosition="right"  value={this.state.hash}
                 onChange={event =>
                   this.setState ({hash: event.target.value})}/>
          </Form.Field>


           <Button loading={this.state.loading} type='submit'>Submit</Button>

          <p> The number of files is {this.state.fileCounts} </p>
          <p> Version 2 The manager of this app is {this.state.manager} </p>
          <p> Your current session is {this.state.accounts} </p>

        </Form>
     </Layout>
    );
  }
}
export default FileNew
```

solidity

```
 struct file {
        string description;
        string hash;
    }

    uint public FileCounts = 0;
    uint public FileId = 0;
    mapping (uint => file) files;
    event _fileCreated(uint indexed id);
    event _fileUpdated(uint indexed id);

    function addFile(string _description, string _hash) public  {
        FileCounts++;
        files[FileId] = file(_description, _hash);
        FileId++;
        emit _fileCreated(FileId);
    }

    function deleteFile(uint id) public restricted {
        delete files[id];
        FileCounts--;
    }

    function getFile(uint id) external constant returns (string, string) {
      file storage F = files[id];

      return (F.description, F.hash);
    }

    function FileCount() public view returns (uint) {
    return FileCounts;
    }


    function getFileDesc(uint id) external constant returns (string) {

      return (files[id].description);
    }
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: what do you mean you want the description and hash displayed? where console.log?

Comment: no, not console.log, in the web interface. I mean i want to have sort of an array that is showing up in the web interface and each time i add file it updates itself automatically with the correspondant hash and description.